# Не устанавливаются куки в requests.Session

Tags: python, requests, cookie

Пытаюсь установить куки в сессию через:

```
import requests
from json import loads


session = requests.Session()
for cookie in loads(open('cookies.json', 'r').read()):
    print(session.cookies.set_cookie(cookie))
```

В cookie попадает словарь вида:

```
{
    "domain": "site",
    "expirationDate": 4785229872,
    "hostOnly": true,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "ips4_recentEmoji",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": null,
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": null,
    "value": "value"
}
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А откуда у вас этот словарь кук?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте передать объект в `set_cookie`

Поменял код (основываясь на [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904567/5909792)):

```
for cookie in loads(open('cookies.json', 'r').read()):
    my_cookie = requests.cookies.create_cookie(**cookie)
    session.cookies.set_cookie(my_cookie)
```

Но это вызвало ошибку из-за наличия запрещенных полей:

```
TypeError: create_cookie() got unexpected keyword arguments: ['expirationDate', 'hostOnly', 'sameSite', 'session', 'storeId', 'httpOnly']
```

Можно удалить эти поля из словаря `cookie`

---

Но, если не важны поля, можно **просто добавить обязательные** `name` и `value` *(и если нужно то в этот метод можно и прочие поля передать)*, пример:

```
for cookie in loads(open('cookies.json').read()):
    session.cookies.set(name=cookie['name'], value=cookie['value'])
```